# Struts2: Not able to get action class boolean variable in jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts2

I have tried to access the boolean variable from action class to jsp page.Please have a look of code below.

### js code

```
<script>
function upload(){
var isZipUpload= $("#languageForm :input[name='isZipUploadFeatureEnable']").val();
alert(isZipUpload);
}
<script>
```

### jsp code

```
<tr>
    <td><s:hidden name="isZipUploadFeatureEnable" label="isZipUploadFeatureEnable" id="isZipUploadFeatureEnable" value="%{isZipUploadFeatureEnable}"/></td>
    <td id="examplePop"><label><b> <s:text name="globalParam.SelectPrompts"></s:text></b></label></td>
</tr>
```

### Action class

```
private boolean isZipUploadFeatureEnable;
public String execute() throws Exception
{
init();
isZipUploadFeatureEnable=true;
}

/**
 * @return the isZipUploadFeatureEnable
 */
public boolean isZipUploadFeatureEnable() {
    return isZipUploadFeatureEnable;
}

/**
 * @param isZipUploadFeatureEnable the isZipUploadFeatureEnable to set
 */
public void setZipUploadFeatureEnable(boolean isZipUploadFeatureEnable) {
    this.isZipUploadFeatureEnable = isZipUploadFeatureEnable;
}
```

value of **isZipUpload** in alert box is came as empty string("").I tried to findout the mistake I didt but no luck.
FYI,I have pasted the same code I am using there is no typo mistake.Please guide me what I forgot or where I did mistake.

Thanks for any help in advance!!

Comment: Unrelated, but please try to keep posted source as concise and as to-the-point as possible. Anything else is just a distraction.

Comment: Is it coming in the hidden tag? Show generated html.

Comment: @AleksandrM no its not comming in hidden tag..its just having empty value

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry if I am not on the point but I just want to make sure to the pepole that I didnt do any silly mistake liketypo mistake and reason for that is when I tried to findout the solution for the same,I found somewhere people ask to check the typo errors in code or pointing to silly mistakes.

Comment: You haven't shown generated html.

Comment: @AleksandrM here is genrated HTML  <INPUT id=isZipUploadFeatureEnable type=hidden name=zipUploadFeatureEnable>   "value" is not coming in html

Answer (score 1):

Your field name is  `isZipUploadFeatureEnable`  in your action code and you have generated getter using eclipse/tool, so it named your getter as `isZipUploadFeatureEnable()` but Struts2 expects your getter as named `isIsZipUploadFeatureEnable()`.
So either rename your field to `zipUploadFeatureEnable` or create getter as `isIsZipUploadFeatureEnable()`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to print response on JSP Page using JSP Scriptlets. All the values coming from action are there and also why are you using JS for assigning values?

You can Simply use same name  tag as your property in Action class it will map it automatically.